# Service for autoplay/stream short videos - mobile

Tags: node.js, video, streaming, video-streaming, ondemand

What I need is to stream short videos (5-10 sec) on user scroll over the video. Something like the instagram, facebook or vine thing.

I tried doing some research, but seems like I can't get to the right thing to search for on Google... therefore I can't get any success in researching what service to use or a way of implementing.

I stumbled upon Wowza, but from what I understand, it seems like a service for live streaming from device to device. And I need to stream short videos, that are stored in a database, only when a user focuses it's screen over the video.

I don't want a solution, but just some initial guidance about what should I be looking into?

P.S. I will be implementing the backend in NodeJS, if that is of any relevance.

Comment: Can't you simply use HTML5 <video>?

Comment: the output is gonna be on mobile device - I will use native for iOS and Android

Comment: The HTML5 `video` tag supports multiple sources, you can have the same file encoded for two platforms if needed while serving them by progressive download/HTTP streaming from a regular HTTP server. MP4/H.264 is a good start for modern mobile devices though the codec is not royalty free, check licensing terms from MPEG-LA. For conversion see the FFmpeg project.